# Why am I having these issues in sxhkd?

Tags: arch-linux, notify-send, sxhkd

First issue:

So, in my `sxhkd` config, I have these lines:

```
super + i; b
    export b=$(acpi); notify-send -t 2000 $b

super +  i; r
    export r=$(free -h | awk '{print $6}' | sed 's/available//'); notify-send -t 2000 'Available memory' $r
```

The first one (battery info), works pretty well, while the second one returns just 'Available memory'. If I run the second command from the terminal, i.e., `export  r=$(free -h | awk '{print $6}' | sed 's/available//'); notify-send -t 2000 'Available memory' $r`, it works right as well. Is their some problem with my syntax in `sxhkd`? I am on Arch.

Second issue:

Well, when the above lines are present in the config, pressing just r or b triggers the `notify-send` commands. How to get the hotkey chord chain right?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it was a silly mistake. I had to escape the braces in `awk`.

```
export  r=$(free -h | awk '\{print $6\}' | sed 's/available//'); notify-send -t 2000 'Available memory' $r
```

This works.